# How to stack (per iteration) dataframes in column side by side in one csv file in python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

If I could generate two columns of data per iteration in a for-loop and I want to save it in a csv file, how will it be done if the next iteration that I would generate two columns it will be stacked side by side on the same csv file(no overwriting)? same goes for the next iterations. I have searched for `pandas.DataFrame(mode='a')` but it only appends the columns vertically (by rows). I have looked into concatenating `pd.concat`, however, I don't know how to implement it in a for loop for more than two `dataframes`. Do you have some sample codes for this one? or some ideas to share?

```
import numpy as np, pandas as pd
for i in xrange (0, 4):
    x = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10).reshape((5,1)))
    y = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10).reshape((5,1)))

    data = np.array([x,y])
    df = pd.DataFrame(data.T, columns=['X','Y'])
```

Comment: IIUC you can `pd.concat([df1, df2, df3, ...], axis=1)`. I think you should update your question with some sample data sets and desired data set, because it's not quite clear...

Comment: i have updated the question,, for i=1, data=np.array([x,y]) will be generated and  for the next iterations, a data set of 8 columns should be produced in one csv file(no overwriting), just horizontally stacking the two- column data per iteration.  any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

A file is a one dimensional object that only grows in length. The rows are only separated by a \n character. So, it is impossible to add rows without rewriting the file.

You can load the file in memory and concatenate using dataframe and then write it back to (some other file). Here:

```
import numpy as np, pandas as pd
a = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10).reshape((5,2)))

b = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(20).reshape((5,4)))

pd.concat([a,b],axis=1)
```

Comment: thanks eafit.. I have  also tried this.. but how can you horizontally concatenate a two -column dataframe (a) in a for -loop that changes every iteration?

Answer (score 1):

is that what you want?

```
In [84]: %paste
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10).reshape((5,2)))

for i in range (0, 4):
    new = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, (5,2)))
    df = pd.concat([df, new], axis=1)
## -- End pasted text --

In [85]: df
Out[85]:
   0  1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1
0  0  1  50  82  24  53  84  65  59  48
1  2  3  26  37  83  28  86  59  38  33
2  4  5  12  25  19  39   1  36  26   9
3  6  7  35  17  46  27  53   5  97  52
4  8  9  45  17   3  85  55   7  94  97
```

Comment: yeah! thanks! but how will it be possible to concatenate two-columned arrays per iteration, such that all of the arrays are changing values?...i.e. changing values of 'new' dataframe per iteration.. then concatenating to the previous values of arrays

Comment: @MaxU yeah it worked but how about if the array to be concatenated is not just generated from randint n x 2 array but for every iteration, the n x 2 array A will be concatenated by nx2 array B,,and so on.. how can a new set of nx2 array be passed into the for loop and be concatenated with the previous.?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative:

```
def iter_stack(n, shape):
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(range(10), shape)).T
    for _ in range(n-1):
        df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(range(10), shape)).T)
    return df.T

iterstacking(5, (5, 2))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the reply.. theres a `NameError: name 'iterstacking' is not defined` .. how about if the array to be concatenated is not just generated from randint n x 2 array but for every iteration, the n x 2 array A will be concatenated by nx2 array B,,and so on.. how can a new set of nx2 array be passed into the for loop and be concatenated with the previous.? ..then save it to one csv file..